# ajax contact form not showing return success

Tags: jquery, ajax

When i click submit, it sends the email but the div i made with the response doesnt show up.

```
$('#enviar').click(function() { 

    all  validation jquery...    
    ....
        if (valid == false){
                return false;
            }else{  
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "enviar.php",
                    data : $('.form_contactos').serialize(),
                    success : function () {
                        $('#ok').fadeIn(1000);
                    }
                });
                return true;    
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning true allows the form to submit. Change it from click to submit for the event handler and always return false which will prevent for form from submitting. I assume the page is reloading which is why you aren't seeing your div.

Comment: i maintained the click but changing the return to false did the trick :) thanks... but now , how do i clean up the message and the inputs?